# Play videos from ASP.NET Core for authorized users

Tags: angular, video, .net-core

I have created an application in Angular as front end. I have used ASP.NET Core as backend. I want to play videos in the Angular application, but there are some restrictions like the user who has registered for video can only play the video.

As we have to allow access to authorized users, I have stored videos in the .NET Core project and enable static files. I can access the videos under `wwwroot` folder.

I have use this approach to authorize the user : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#static-file-authorization. it returns physical file.

Now my question is: when I use the ASP.NET Core API method name which returns physical file in video tag source url, it does not play the video. Can we add api get method as video tag source url, if not than how can i play the video from the physical file returned by the Api methods.

Comment: There seem to be multiple questions here, and the current state of your problem is unclear. Can you narrow down your question to show some C# [mcve]? Is there a problem in authenticating the problem generally on your site, or just for the download (play the video)?

Comment: hi Pac0, i have edited my question. When i return the video from the ASP.NET Core API how can i play it in angular project.